# Visual Studio 2005 Freezing

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I am running Visual Studio 2005 Team Edition and I am having trouble as it is freezing quite a lot.

I have the freezing issue when I save files or change what I am doing. By 'change what I am doing' I really mean anything. I might be editing a file and then click on a file in the Solution Explorer and then the IDE will freeze. I might just change between files that I am working (using the file tabs). I would say that the freezing occurs more often when I am working on projects that contain a large number of files.

The freezing is very frustrating as I literally have to sit and wait, or make a coffee.

I have installed SP1 and have not noticed any difference. I have also followed the steps outlined on '.Net Tip of the Day': http://dotnettipoftheday.org/tips/speedup_visual_studio.aspx. I did notice a difference from the changes suggested, the IDE runs faster but I still get my freezing problem as often.

My PC does not have the greatest spec, it has a Pentium 4 CPU 3.00GHz with 2GB RAM, but I think it should be sufficient. I have experienced the same problem on new and faster PCs too.

If anyone has any ideas or advice I will be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are you using?  VS2005 has known issues with Vista.  I experienced the same problems and eventually gave up and upgraded to 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on a similar spec machine - I resolved them with two steps that have completely transformed my user experience.

1. Upgrade your memory to 4Gb - any swapping that occurs because of memory used by the OS or other running applications has a big impact on the usability of VS.
2. Add another physical hard drive to your machine and keep your solution and source files on a different physical drive (not just a different logical partion) from your OS and VS install.

My machine has gone from struggling to page down in the IDE to being fully interactive with much reduced compile times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately my system is limited to 2GB. I have heard about the additional drive option so with both suggestions I have something to think about. It sounds like it is time for a new PC. Are you running XP still?